Classifying extensions of modules $\bigoplus_i A_i$ by $\bigoplus_j B_j$ using extensions of $A_i$ by $B_j$ for all $i,j$.
Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring, $A=\bigoplus_i A_i$ and $B=\bigoplus_j B_j$ be finite direct sums of $R$-modules. I want to classify the extensions of $A$ by $B$, and have managed to classify the extensions of $A_i$ by $B_j$ for all $i,j$. In all cases that I am interested in there are only finitely many extensions up to isomorphism i.e. all Ext modules are finite. Of course, $$\text{Ext}(A,B)=\bigoplus_{i,j}\text{Ext}(A_i,B_j),$$ so it should be possible to find all extensions of $A$ by $B$ i.e. all $$0\to B\to X\to A\to 0$$ using the extensions $$0\to B_j\to X\to A_i\to 0$$ that I have already found. But I am unsure how this works in practice. In some concrete examples, I have taken direct sums of short exact sequences involving $A_i$ and $B_j$ to form extensions of $A$ by $B$, but this hasn't given enough extensions, so I'm wondering if there are others that can't be constructed in this manner.
How can I use my knowledge of the extensions of components to find extensions of the direct sums?

I think the instance where this theorem really shines is when $A,B$ re two finitely generated abelian groups, because then $A\cong \mathbb Z^a \oplus \bigoplus \mathbb Z/n_i\mathbb Z$, $B\cong \mathbb Z^b\oplus\bigoplus\mathbb Z/m_j\mathbb Z$, and then computing $\text{Ext}^1(A,B)$ is reduced to computing $\text{Ext}^1(\mathbb Z/s\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z/t\mathbb Z)$ and $\text{Ext}^1(\mathbb Z/s\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z/s\mathbb Z$.

Hint. This will work in any abelian category. Start with two summands. And let's focus on the second variable first (the first one will be very similar). The canonical homomorphism $Ext(A,B) \oplus Ext(A,B') \to Ext(A,B \oplus B')$ is induced by the homomorphisms $Ext(A,B) \to Ext(A,B \oplus B')$ and $Ext(A,B') \to Ext(A,B \oplus B')$, which in turn are induced by the inclusions $i_1,i_2$ into the direct sum. So you only need to describe

the group structure
the functoriality (in the 2nd variable)

of the Ext modules in terms of the extensions. Both should be easy to locate in the literature. If you have that, two extensions $E,E'$ of $A$ by $B,B'$ correspond to the extension $(i_1)_*(E) +(i_2)_*(E')$ of $A$ by $B \oplus B'$.

Thanks for this. Am I right in thinking then that if I take an extension $B_1\oplus B_2$ by $A$, find the associated element of $\text{Ext}
(B_1\oplus B_2,A)$, then the extensions corresponding to the components in  $\text{Ext}(B_1,A)$ and $\text{Ext}(B_2,A)$ should combine in some way to give to the original one? I am a bit confused here as I can only see how to combine them together 'pointwise' i.e. taking an extension $B_1$ by $A_1$ and $B_2$ by $A_2$ to give an extension $B_1\oplus B_2$ by $A_1\oplus A_2$ (direct sum of short exact sequences)
